# Android background selector and textcolor selector conflict

Tags: android, selector, textview, android-selector, android-viewgroup

I set a background selector to a ViewGroup, and this ViewGroup has a child TextView, I set a selector to textColor, then I press this ViewGroup, the TextView'textColor dismissed in pressed state.

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

**1. Create background drawable for ViewGroup**

**1.a. color resources:** (colors.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
  <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
  <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>

  <color name="blue_grey_200">#B0BEC5</color>
</resources>
```

**1.b. ViewGroup normal state:** (drawable_viewgroup_normal.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/blue_grey_200" />
</shape>
```

**1.c. ViewGroup pressed state:** (drawable_viewgroup_press.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/blue_grey_200" />
<stroke
    android:width="0.7dp"
    android:color="@color/blue_grey_200" />
</shape>
```

**1.d. ViewGroup selector background:** (selector_viewgroup.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_viewgroup_press" android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_viewgroup_press" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_viewgroup_normal"/>
</selector>
```

**2. Create selector text color for ViewGroup's child(TextView)** selector_viewgroup_child_textcolor.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/white"/>
  <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/white"/>
  <item android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
</selector>
```

**3. Apply selector drawables to ViewGroup and their Child**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/l1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_viewgroup"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin8">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textColor="@drawable/selector_viewgroup_child_textcolor" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**4. Result**

Normal state:

[image: Normal state]

Pressed state:

[image: Pressed state]

Comment: Thank you very much , I have resolved it as your method.

Answer (score 0):

it's because your textview color is related with selector file "selector_viewgroup_child_textcolor.xml",you have set press state and normal state,if you want the textview's color is immutable,ensure your textcolor is not refer to any seletor files